# Is there anyway to bind a command to all instances of a button in a user control in XAML / WPF / MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, repeat

My problem is that I have a lot of code doing the same thing. All the buttons in my stackpanel trigger a command and with that command I want to send a parameter to a method in my view model.

I have the following XAML code, as you can see it is ridiculously repetitive:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Row" Grid.Row="4">
    <Button Content="z" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Content="x" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Content="c" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Content="v" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Content="b" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Content="n" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
    <Button Content="m" 
        Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way I can reduce the amount of repetitive code, either in the XAML or View Model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not try `Template` or `Style`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution that works, assuming you have buttons and command binding done at one place or else the first answer (seen the answer after my post) gives you easiest way by putting under an ItemsControl and do the stuff.

```
   <StackPanel x:Name="Row" Grid.Row="4">
              <StackPanel.Resources>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" />
                      <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"
  />
                  </Style>
              </StackPanel.Resources>
              <Button Content="z"  />
              <Button Content="x"  />
              <Button Content="c"  />
              <Button Content="v"  />
              <Button Content="b"  />
              <Button Content="n"  />
              <Button Content="m"  />
          </StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: This only binds command to the buttons inside the stackpanel. If you want all buttons inside a control/window, then add same logic under Windows.Resources or UserControl.Resources

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of items in your ViewModel, for example

```
public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string> { "x", "c", "v", "..." };
```

And assign it to the `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Row" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding }" 
                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` says what container to use for these items and `ItemTemplate` defines what each element of `StackPanel` should look like.

Binding inside `DataTemplate` refers to `string` that's why in order to get to the `ButtonClickCommand` we have to go back to `ItemsControl`'s context.

Comment: Also the Command need a relative binding - the command is not a property of the data item. `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"`